# hadoop 2.7.1 Jobs Status UI not up and running

Tags: hadoop

I have started the services using start-dfs.sh.
But i still dont see 50030 port being up to know the status of Jobs.
50070 port is up and running. need to know if any specific thing has to be set for 50030 port to bring it up.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Access your server on port 50070 for almost all options. 
Access port 8088 for getting the information about cluster and all applications.
Access port 50090 for getting details about secondary namenode.
Access port 50075 to get details about DataNode.*

A job status can be viewed at port 8088.

Job tracker can be accessed on port 50030, without any additional configuration or changes.